# What does $P(i,k\mid i,k + 1) = 1$ mean?

Tags: probability, statistics

Thanks in advance for the help.

I'm reading a paper and came across the following probability $P(i,k\mid i,k + 1) = 1$.  I am familiar with $P(k\mid i) = t$ which essentially means the probability of $k$ given $i$ is $t$, but I haven't seen $P(i,k\mid i,k + 1) = 1$ before.  What is the proper way to interpret this?

Edit,
Here is the paper

https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/4a5c/f874e9469815113c7ea93ff97317bdb52a90.pdf

The authors are using $P(i,k\mid i,k + 1) = 1$ as a shorthand notation, but this doesn't affect the meaning of this notation $P(,,)$.  It is not clear to me what this notation is meant to represent.

Comment: It's probably a frequently used sloppy notation for a conditional probability mass function.  To be specific enough I'd probably want to see more of the context. $\qquad$

Comment: There is probably (!) a random process $(X_n)$ behind all this, such that $P(X_{n+1}=(i,k)\mid X_n=(i,k+1))=1$ for every suitable $n$ and $(i,k)$.

Comment: I added a link to the paper (it's on page two bottom of left hand column)

Comment: Thus, precisely my comment with $X_n=(s(n),b(n))$.

Comment: ahhh ok, I understand.  Thank you very much.  If you want to write out an answer I will accept it (otherwise I will write up one in maybe in hour or so).